# Incorrect getComputedStyle result for CSS Transform over SVG

Tags: javascript, css, svg, css-animations

I use getComputedStyle to get css transform value from some SVG Elements while doing CSS animation. For example,

```
<svg width="100px" height="100px">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="10" style="transform:translate(50%,50%)"/>
</svg>
<script>
  var ret = window.getComputedStyle(circle).transform;
  /* ret = matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0) in chrome */
  /* ret = matrix(1,0,0,1,50,50) in firefox */
</script>
```

however I got "`matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)`" (identity matrix) in `ret`, which  ignored the style I set with `translate(50%,50%)`.

If I use pixel as unit then it works correctly:

```
<svg width="100px" height="100px">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="10" style="transform:translate(10px,10px)"/>
</svg>
<script>
  var ret = window.getComputedStyle(circle).transform;
  /* ret = matrix(1,0,0,1,10,10) in both chrome and firefox */
</script>
```

Since percentage here should be related to element's dimension, the result from getComputedStyle should have the identical result as `matrix(1,0,0,1,10,10)`.

Not sure if this is a bug in browsers or what, but - is there any way for now to get correct and consistent value in at least both Chrome and Firefox?

Comment: Sounds like a Chrome bug which you can report here: https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines

Answer (score 1):

Can you try it with **your element**[.getBoundingClientRect().transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect). Sometimes window.getComputedStyle return different values for different browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I needed the position of the element inside svg and for that I used getBoundingClientRect() for both child and parent element and then calculated the position with them.